# Adding dynamic parameters in fremarker android studio

Tags: templates, plugins, android-studio, freemarker

I am creating a template using freemarker. I want to add few parameters at runtime. How it can be done. The following is a sample template code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<template
    minApi="7"
    minBuildApi="8">

<category  />

<dependency name="android-support-v4" revision="8" />

<parameter
    id="packageName"
    name="Package name"
    type="string"
    constraints="package"
    default="com.mycompany.myapp" />

...
...
...

<!-- 128x128 thumbnails relative to template.xml -->
<thumbs>
    <!-- default thumbnail is required -->
    <thumb>thumb_file.png</thumb>
</thumbs>


<globals file="globals.xml.ftl" />
<execute file="recipe.xml.ftl" />
```

I want to generate a parameter while clicking a button in the template. Is it possible to do so? Is there any proper documentation available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `visibility` attribute. For example, in the following:

```
<parameter
    id="includeLayout"
    name="Create layout XML?"
    type="boolean"
    default="true"
    help="Generate a layout XML" />

<parameter
    id="layoutName"
    name="Layout Name"
    type="string"
    constraints="layout|nonempty|unique"
    default="fragment_default"
    visibility="includeLayout"
    suggest="fragment_${camelCaseToUnderscore(className)}"
    help="The name of the fragment layout to create" />
```

`visibility="includeLayout"` means that that field will only be visible when `includeLayout` is checked as true

Comment: Thanks for the response @gnardini. But I want to add new fields according to users input.